# how can i fill these boundaries by quad topology?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, faces

I am currently modelling a Audi R8(2016). I am doing the part behind the door. However i have a problem in filling up these faces[image]

I have tried using the grid fill tool but it doesn't work out well. It creates a weird seam in the middle part.
[image]

I want a topology somewhat like this.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.Thank You In Advance.

Comment: If you mean "with a quad-based topology good for SubSurf" I think that there is no tool able to do that with few step. The shape is convex and has several variations of vertex density along the boundary. Can you show what kind of "edge flow" you would like to obtain? You can composite several picture in a bigger one to avoid reputation's limitation.

Comment: Ya i will post it tomorow. Thanks for the suggestio Carlo

Comment: maybe you could share a .blend with only that segment of the car so we can attempt to provide more automated solutions.  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok i will post it as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

I saw this pop up and even though it is an old question thought it worthwhile putting forward an answer. The original image is not great but here is a mesh that will work and is adaptable.

[image]

With matcap in object mode and a subdivison surface x 2

[image]

A simple bend deformer applied shows the deformation without any artifacts/creasing/lighting issues.

[image]

Extruded with bend modifier

[image]

Comment: This looks good. How was it created?

Answer (score -2):

You could first add a Face with F (a Ngon) and then split it with J or with K (for Knife Tool) until you get a pattern whats similar to what you have drawn in your post.

Comment: Wtf! did you even read the question? I recommend removing your answer.

Comment: @KaarelParve first off my first part of my answer isn't about grid fill at all and is definitely a valid answer (I do it that way all the time and it seems to be efficient enough) and the second part is about the fact that grid fill is versatile and can adapt, but won't necessarily do it automatic.

Answer (score -4):

The following will make all of the vertices one big face.

1. Select all of the vertices of what you want to fill
2. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill the vertices

Comment: that will make a big N-gon, the OP is asking for a way to create quads.